# Loading exported environment variable in python script

Tags: python, environment-variables

I am running a python script inside a batch one. I want to export a batch variable and load it in python command lines, like below:

```
#!/bin/bash -l
#SBATCH -n 32
#SBATCH -N 1
#SBATCH -t 24:00:00

export OMP_NUM_THREADS=1
APRUN_OPTIONS="-n 32 -d 1 -cc none"

python script.py
```

and then, inside python script, when I submit it using I have:

```
aprun_opts = os.environ['APRUN_OPTIONS']
command = "aprun " + aprun_opts + " command_execute"
```

os.system(command)

So far, i get the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "script.py", line 11, in <module>
    aprun_opts = os.environ['APRUN_OPTIONS']
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/UserDict.py", line 22, in __getitem__   raise KeyError(key)
KeyError: 'APRUN_OPTIONS'
```

Does anyone can see the problem?
Thanks!

Comment: I removed the "batch file" mentions since that's Windows speak and your traceback indicates you are running Linux. You should probably also pick a better tag than "variables".

Comment: I think you should post your shell script. If I run a two-line Python script that just accesses an environment variable after exporting it runs just as expected.

Comment: it works for me when running `export APRUN_OPTIONS="-n 32 -d 1"` and then `python script.py`, I don't get any error.

Comment: Shell script added, so as python commands

Comment: The problem is that you're not exporting APRUN_OPTIONS

Comment: As an aside, this is why it's important to post your code! You described in the question that you want to "export a variable" for use in your Python script -- well, that works, so we cannot reproduce. Yet in your code, you fail to do so! If you had posted it at first, the solution would have been obvious and you would have gotten your answer instantly.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need `APRUN_OPTIONS` elsewhere in your script, you can simply do

```
APRUN_OPTIONS="-n 32 -d 1" python script.py
```

Note that they're on the same line and there's no `export`.